# The user control that is opened in custom task pane of outlook plugin, doesn't get disposed when the pane is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook plugin.I added a button in outlook toolbar, and when the user clicks that button, a webservice is called.Depending upon the result of that webservice a usercontrol is loaded in a custom task pane.When a user closes the custom task pane, I call the dispose method on the user control.I also dispose the child control of this user control in its disposed event and removed the custom task pane from the customtaskpanes list.But the memory is not released.I also disposed the custom task pane.But nothing happened.So, is it a problem with my coding, or is it a problem with outlook?I am working with winforms on .net framework 3.5.The memory taken by outlook keeps on increasing whenever I press the button.

Comment: Have you inspected your application with memory profiler? This will let you know what objects aren't released from memory and is your best bet to finding what actually causes the issue.

Comment: I know that the user control is not getting disposed

Comment: How much time did you click the button? Maybe the garbage collector didn't decide yet to collect memory.

Comment: I clicked it many times.SO many times that the outlook crashed.It took memory close to 1 GB without releasing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell if a memory leak occurs without any code sample. Keep in mind that analyzing managed memory can be tricky...

However, my suggestion is that you probably should not dispose your VSTO task pane controls manually. If the user clicks the hide task pane, the task pane is not "destroyed" and you should not unregister it. Its Visible property is set to `false`.
See sample code below in my Startup.addin.cs that enables to Toggle the TaskPane visibility.

```
        public const string productName = "myMillionDollarAddin";
        private void RegisterTaskPane()
        {
            var tskControl = new TaskPaneControl();
            CustomTaskPane taskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(tskControl, productName);
            taskPane.Visible = true;
        }

        public void ShowHideTaskPane()
        {
            var taskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.FirstOrDefault(ctp => ctp.Title == productName);
            if (taskPane == null)
            {
                RegisterTaskPane();
            }
            else
            {
                var visibility = taskPane.Visible;
                taskPane.Visible = !visibility;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanx,your code helped a lot.The outlook used to take up approx 5 mb extra space each time, I used to click button.But now it takes only about 200 KB.Can, this 200 KB also be removed.Because now all I am doing is making a webservice call.

Comment: Hi, if toggling the task pane visibility is the approach you take, please mark the answer as accepted. Now regarding the memory management, for a .NET process IMHO, you should not try to investigate memory without a memory profiler. You may want to flush the data from the web service call (if they are voluminous)  so they will be garbage collected. But you should not try to optimize 200KB of managed memory by cleaning the form controls. The following [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/redgatebooks/ChrisFarrell/Under_the_Hood_of_NET_Management.pdf) is a must read for all .NET developers.

Comment: I was going to mark it as answered after your reply.Because, if I would've done it before then , you probably wouldn't have replied.